# Stripe oAuth Token Url Blocked

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to fetch account details through stripe auth code but i have getting error
Access to fetch at 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
const url =
"https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token";

```
     const formData = new URLSearchParams();
     formData.append("code", this.code);
      formData.append("client_secret", this.secretKey);
      formData.append("grant_type",'authorization_code');

      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          authorization: "Bearer " + environment.stripeSkKey,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        
          
        },
        body: formData,
      })
       .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
          console.warn(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.warn(err);
        });
```

Comment: It looks like this is your frontend code, but you're exposing sensitive information (your Stripe secret key and OAuth details), which is a significant security issue.  Can you provide more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: i have applied code for registering user on stripe so after redirecting back stripe provides a 'code' parameter through which we can fetch that registered user stripe account number through API "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token"  i am doing this in local so i am facing that error

Comment: The issue you're experiencing is due to CORS, but you should not be making this kind of request from frontend code, as doing so is not secure.  This kind of request should be made from a secure sever where CORS will not be an issue.